# How to store web logic server console into file

Tags: java, weblogic11g

How i can store the server output console into `server.log` -like the output of netbeans apache output console `server.log` to trace sql errors and display `system.out.println`

**`i have tried`** to configure the logging and debug section in weblogic administration control but i cant find a clue to for my problem ,the server.log exist store the http requests and other things that is not important to me ,i read references and manuals "fast read" so if someone can give me a reference to my problem or solution may be because i cant find the appropriate terminology to search

example

```
the Form Action is :searchEmNominativeInterviewPrevInvertory

=========EXTRA PARAMETER FOR SEARCH=========

Extra Parameters

=========EXTRA PARAMETER FOR SEARCH=========

-----<<>>----trying to get connection--3---
PDAO 
PDAO user
PDAO null
PDAO  1 = 1  AND REQ_CLASS = 'I'
PDAO 
PDAO 
PDAO -1
PDAO -1
PDAO null
PDAO -1
PDAO -1
PDAO -1
PDAO -1
PDAO I
PDAO -1
PDAO -1
PDAO 9481007150
PDAO 1
PDAO 13
PDAO 
PDAO 
-----<<>>----Executing the Security Procedure Fail...
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: سطر 1 ، عمود  7 : 
PLS-00905: object HR2_EMPL.EM_NOM_INTER_PREV_STOCK$SELECT is invalid
ORA-06550: سطر 1 ، عمود  7 : 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:215)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:954)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3390)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4223)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:169)
        at com.rss.components.ParentDAO.executeProcedure(ParentDAO.java:318)
        at rss.hr2.recruitment.RecruitmentDAO.searchEmNominativeInterviewPrevInvertory(RecruitmentDAO.java:15051)
        at rss.hr2.recruitment.interviews.searchEmNominativeInterviewPrevInvertory.execute(searchEmNominativeInterviewPrevInvertory.java:159)
        at rss.controller.CommandDispatcher.executeCommand(CommandDispatcher.java:111)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link has the solution to my problem

[Reference To Configure *log4j* In Weblogic Server](http://ananthkannan.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-configure-log4j-in-weblogic.html)

[oracle docs on How to Use Log4j with WebLogic Logging Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/logging/config_logs.html#1014610)

The First link Content first paragraph read the link for the reset

Configure log4j in weblogic server
I have recently configured log4j for our web applications deployed in weblogic 10.3 domain. The steps are given below:

1. Copy `log4j-1.2.9.jar & wllog4j.jar` under `domain_root/lib folder`.
2. Create `log4j.xml` and drop it under domain_root folder. If you have log4j.xml inside the application(EAR/WAR), I would recommend to move outside EAR/WAR 
   as changing severity (log level) would require re-deployment. 
   To avoid this, we can move log4j.xml into domain root folder but again the server needs to be bounced. But there is a fix. Click here for more info.
3. Login to weblogic server console. `Go to Servers ->  Admin Server-> Logging.` 
   Click on advanced mode. Change the logging implementation from `JDK to Log4J.` Click save.
4. Activate changes. Re-start the admin server.

This should enable log4j and should write logging into log file mentioned in `log4j.xml or properties file`.

if you want an example i recommend this [log4j - Quick Guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_quick_guide.htm)

advice you should be patience to read and apply

Comment: if you have a problem working with log4j you can invite me for a chat but not at work time the comment time in my local 09:00 AM and UTC 7:00

Answer (score 1):

Server console logs can be redirected to log files.

```
Adminstration Console - Server (Your server Name) - Logging - Redirect stdout logging enabled

Adminstration Console - Server (Your server Name) - Logging - Redirect stderr logging enabled
```

Though the stack trace that you have should be handled as part of application logging.

Complete Weblogic Server Logging can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13739/config_logs.htm).

Edit:

Moved from comments below:

[Log4j Tutorial](http://tutorialspoint.com/log4j/index.htm).

Comment: i`ve got the idea the the keyword am looking for is Redirecting JVM Output but i cant find your code in the reference

Comment: I am not sure where in reference this is mentioned, I actually logged into my play weblogic Env and gave you the path

Comment: i found about log4j and i think i will use it in my web app MVC thanks pal i need working steps to do it only +1

Comment: yeah correct, you should have your application logging separate and should be directed towards a specific file rather than console. You can check this [link](https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/How+to+setup+Log4j+in+a+web+app+-+fast) for a starting point with log4j for web application.

Comment: actually i found this link better [LINK] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/index.htm) it has all about dealing with classpath and path and log4j.properties and Logging in Database thankyou i hope every one find this post use this link and learn something new

Comment: Indeed a good point... I will add your link in the post... thanks for sharing

Comment: thanks for the tip i did not know about log4j i used it so cool